# A question related to NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone

I have set,

This is my below code in applicationwillterminate method.

```
NSString *string4 = @"Objective-C";

NSUserDefaults* defs7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defs7 setObject:string4 forKey:@"subject_textfield"];
```

This is my below code in applicationdidfinishlaunching method.

```
NSUserDefaults* defs7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
subject_textfield.text = [defs7 stringForKey:@"subject_textfield"];
```

but,when i press home and then i again launch application
at that time i'm getting nil value for subject_textfield.text.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` to enforce that NSUserDefaults are getting saved.

Reference:

> Because this method is automatically
>   invoked at periodic intervals, use
>   this method only if you cannot wait
>   for the automatic synchronization (for
>   example, if your application is about
>   to exit) or if you want to update the
>   user defaults to what is on disk even
>   though you have not made any changes.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDEGI

Answer (score 1):

`applicationwillterminate` may not be called in `iOS4`. If you are on iOS4, check out the following events:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
applicationWillResignActive

applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationDidBecomeActive
```